# Issue On Setting SEO For My Website

Tags: seo, google-search

Can you Please take a look at [This Demo](http://tandfsprayfoamsystems.com/spray-foam-insulation-services-in-vancouver/) and let me know why This Page of my Website is Presenting in Google Search engine instead of My [First Page (Home Page)](http://tandfsprayfoamsystems.com/). As far as I know and learned from Google SEO Tutorial I followed every thing standard for SEO on home Page! If you search Google with "vancouver spray foam insulation" criteria the page shows at 4th page of google.ca Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your home will not always be #1 for search on Google. The reason is simple. Google is trying to satisfy the search criteria and likely your referred to page ranks higher for the search terms used. It is a mistake to look for your home page to always rank higher than other pages. Generally, it would not because most home pages are diluted representing the whole site and not a specific topic.

Comment: Thanks closetnoc, Do you think I have to update the Home page to some thing like above Demo Page?

Comment: I would update your product (demo) page to compete stronger. Indeed I would do this for any product page.